# Verify Laravel password in iOS app offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, laravel, hash, bcrypt

I'm creating an app that hooks to a Laravel backend. I've got my user table downloaded and stored on the app for offline. Now I need to figure out how to allow login to the app, ideally using the same password that was created in the Laravel backend.

I've done a little digging and see that Laravel uses the password_hash and password_verify php functions with bcrypt. I've installed this [bcrypt library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JFBCrypt) but still not quite able to put all the pieces together.

I need the app to function fully offline, and I really do not want to have to create separate passwords.

Does anyone have any insight?

Thank you

Comment: Is this only for your self/business or for public appstores?

Comment: In the end it will be public on the app store. I think that's what you're asking? Is there some considerations in getting it through Apple?

Comment: i think it's not secure enough to safe ALL of your user data (including email, password) to you local phone(s) instead of your server.

Comment: Ah, I might've misrepresented it. It will be used by businesses and they'll be connecting devices to their database of user data. There will be some initial authentication for each business to hook devices up to the right database.